# How to delete one or more of the efficiency of records in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle

> delete from t_a where t_a.id in ('1', '2', '3')

or

> delete from t_a where t_a.id ???

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from t_a where t_a.id in ('1', '2', '3')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from t_a where t_a.id in ('1', '2', '3')
```

vs

```
delete from t_a where t_a.id = '1';
delete from t_a where t_a.id = '2';
delete from t_a where t_a.id = '3';
```

In case you have an index on id column, the efficiency will be almost the same.

In case you don't have index on id column, the first will be faster because the first will do a **single** full scan on t_a table, the second way will do **three** full scans.

Just for the ideea: best efficiency you'll get if you have the table t_a index organized:

```
CREATE TABLE t_a
(
  id    NUMBER,
  col2  VARCHAR2(10), 
  CONSTRAINT id_pk
  PRIMARY KEY
  (id)
)
ORGANIZATION INDEX;
```

but you should use this with care(documented first).

Answer (score 0):

What's your point ? You want to compare this 2 methods to get the faster way deleting data within the rules or what?